# how to pass the value of one input to another input's onBlur event in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I have two date time fields on reactjs form as

```
<div>
   <input type="text" name="startdate" value={this.state.startDate}  onBlur={this.validateStartDate} /> 
    <input type="text" name="enddate"value={this.state.endDate} onBlur={this.validateEndDate}/> 
</div>
```

I want to validate the startdate, whether it is less than endDate or not, 
How to pass the endDate value to the validateStartDate function?
 or 
If there is a better way to validate the input date fields, please provide the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you're storing your `endDate` as a state. So, when the user blurs `startDate` call `validateStartDate`. In that function, use the `endDate` state value to validate.

See the pseudo code

```
<div>
   <input type="text" name="startdate" value={this.state.startDate}  onBlur={this.validateStartDate} /> 
    <input type="text" name="enddate"value={this.state.endDate} onBlur={this.validateEndDate}/> 
</div>

function validateStartDate(){
   //check this.state.startDate < this.state.endDate
}
```

Or, you can use `refs` to get the `endDate` value.

```
<div>
   <input type="text" ref="startDate" name="startdate" value={this.state.startDate}  onBlur={this.validateStartDate} /> 
    <input type="text" ref="endDate" name="enddate"value={this.state.endDate} onBlur={this.validateEndDate}/> 
</div>

function validateStartDate(){
   var startDate= ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.startDate).value
   var endDate = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.endDate).value
   //check startDate < endDate
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: i tried your first suggestion previously, but i didn't mention it my issue. I got TypeError: this.state is undefined error in the console

Comment: Add `this.validateStartDate = this.validateStartDate.bind(this)` in your constructor.

Comment: I don't want to use refs, is there any other way to approach this issue.

Comment: Try my first suggestion.

Comment: That's the efficient one

Answer (score 0):

you can use refs supported by react.[Check here for official documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html)

```
<div>
    <input type="text" name="startdate" ref= (input) => {this.startData = input.value; } value={this.state.startDate}  onBlur={this.validateStartDate}  /> 
    <input type="text" name="enddate"value={this.state.endDate} onBlur={this.validateEndDate}/> 
</div>
```

In `validateEndDate` function you can reference the ref.

```
validateEndDate(){
    //you can use this.startDate here
}
```

**NOTE: Refs do not work in stateless function components**